# Classification from a string of numbers and letters

Tags: python, machine-learning

I have a database full of items and I've been tasked with classifying them (they could be books, stationary etc). The options are to either go through 100k records manually and figure out what they are or to automate the task.

The codes for each type of item follow some kind of pattern, and so I'm hoping to use machine learning to solve this (I do not want to use regular expressions). Though I'm quite good at python, my ml knowledge only goes as far as random forests and logistic regression.

Is this at all possible? The data looks like this:

```
Item          code          type
1       4S2BDANC5L3247151   book
2       1N4AL3AP1JC236284   book
3       3R4BTTGC3L3237430   book
4       KNMAT2MT1KP546287   book
5       97806773062273208   pen
6       07356196706378892   Pen
7       97807345361169253   pen
8       01008130715194136   chair
9       01076305063010CCE44 chair
etc
```

I'm happy to look up and learn whatever is necessary, I just don't know where to start
Thanks!

Comment: Does the length of code have a max and min size?

Comment: sadly no, the lengths can change

Answer (score 0):

I understood that you have 100k example. You can use RNN, LSTM or Attention based deep learning methods because the pattern of codes can be tracked by that models. Also machine learning models can solve that problem. In the end, your problem includes specific type of patterns for different classes. Therefore, you can separate that classes.

**1)** *You need to start with finding embedding to represent your codes. I guess you can use ascii codes of numbers and letters. Also to make all vectors be the same length, use padding. Then you can normalize them to put in between 0-1.*

**2)** *Then my advise is to start with SVM with one-vs-all strategy to make multi-class classification. After that you can try XGBoost, which is a powerful ml model. Or you can start with more basic ml models. Idea behind that, start from basic and goes to complicated models.*

**3)** *If ml models are not enough for that task, start with basic RNN models.*

I don't know about your data distribution among classes and also number of classes. If it is balanced and each class have enough data I guess you can easily automate that task.